# What problems can I expect using a 13.10 saucy repository in 14.04 trusty?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, repository

I just installed VirtualBox 4.3.10 for Linux following the instructions that I found at [this site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), but the latest repository available is for Ubuntu 13.10, not Ubuntu 14.04. This is the source that I appended to my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib
```

I tried to just replace the word `saucy` with `trusty`, but that repository is not found it gives a 404 error. However, I was able to use the saucy source and every thing seems to be working properly so far. The installation went smoothly. I do plan on checking periodically to see when VirtualBox does update to trusty source so that I can get rid of the saucy source.

My main question here is this going to cause me any serious problems later on, or does it really not matter too much?

---

**Update: No longer a problem.**

The VirturalBox web site has now made their update to trusty 14.04 repository.

Comment: In my case, it was using older versions of libraries that were no longer available in Trusty (if you uninstalled them, you have to get them manually). I would personally stay on the trusty version so that you know when the trusty version goes live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will be safe to assume that at least until an newer repository becomes available it will be safe for me to use the older version.